# ArcGIS10.0 (32 bit) waits for splwow64.exe indefinitely and stops responding

Tags: arcgis-10.0, extensions

I am running ArcMap 10.0 (32 bit) on Windows 7 (64 bit), while using some extensions the application waits indefinitely for splwow64.exe and then either crashes or stops responding, shall I try running application on a 32 bit system ?

Comment: I have this concern as well. I am trying to draw buffers around shapes and ArcMAP will not draw a single one. When I look in the resource manager, it says that wait chain is waiting for splwow64.exe. I've tried restarting the print spooler and it hasn't helped either. I can't trace this behavior back to any specific moment. Just yesterday, my computer was drawing buffers just fine. I've reinstalled ArcGIS 10.4 from scratch. I haven't tried formatting my computer, as I don't think it should come to that. Definitely very strange behavior from my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the Windows Print Spooler service (or just reboot your machine if that's easier for you). The print spooler is hosted in that process and might be causing problems.

Comment: The status remains "Not Responding", I have tried both of the above mentioned ways to tackle the issue, unfortunately none of them helps.

Comment: Also tried "Stop Print Spooler" permanently before launching application instead of restarting it during the process, nothing helps.

Comment: I'd urge you to submit a support an incident to Esri Support Services so this can be evaluated and tracked.